# @php instead of <?php in Atom editor after update

Tags: php, atom-editor

After the update, I updated about 7 packages - including Atom - right now when I write `php` and hit tab inside a blade file (Laravel), it's expanded into

```
@php

@endphp
```

however, what I want is

```
<?php

?>
```

How to do that?

Which file should I edit to get it back? I have looked into

snippets.cson (Edit  -> Snippets...)

But this file is empty - contains only a comment with info how to create a snippet.

Comment: There is no way for us to know which packages you have installed. I don't think there's another way than disabling packages one by one to find the reason for this behaviour. The [creation of snippet](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/) is well-documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `snippets.json` is empty by default. Adding your own snippets should override those that come with packages. It should look something like this:

```
'.text.html.php.blade':
  '<?php … ?>':
    'prefix': 'php'
    'body': '<?php $0 ?>'
```

Optionally, you can add line-breaks, e.g. `'body': '<?php\n\t$0\n?>`'.

Comment: Not, working. I have added your code into my `snippets.cson` file but if I have a `something.blade.php` file it is still firing `@php @endphp` instead `<?php ?>`. I have restarted Atom, but it's not working. Notice that if I have a regular php file and not a blade file e.g. `something.php` it's working OK and `<?php ?>` is shown after pressing the tab key, However, inside of the `something.blade.php` file I get the `@php @endphp`.

Comment: Change the scope of the snippet from `.text.html.php` to `text.html.php.blade`?

Comment: ;D Thanks! Adding blade after php helped.